After trying to log in to github account the idea.key file is deleted
Up to now I have had no problems with Intellij IDEA (installed via Toolbox) on my ubuntu the version I am working on is IntelliJIdea2024.2 yesterday I was interested in the AI ​​plugin and I used log in to the github account (I had Intellij activated with an activation code).
In the older version (IntelliJIdea2024.1) files I have idea.key after copying to the current version it initially shows that the product is active but after some time I get a message to activate.
Has anyone tried to recover the code from idea.key?
Or do I need to delete or change something after copying idea.key?
I have some activation code but it indicates that it is not correct it is possible that I have changed it in the meantime.
Has anyone tried to recover the activation code from the computer?
